# C# (or any other code because the only needed is the logic) - Condition to permanently disable a previous condition

Tags: c#, if-statement

I need to know a simplified way to have a condition that permanent "disables" the event from a previous condition already met.

Maybe I'm not using the correct terms but I will explain what I need with an example.

Having the condition:

```
if (a > 10)
{
   print ("Correct");
}
```

Let's suppose the condition is met and printing the message `Correct` as should, **but** later the next new condition is met (important, after the 1st condition is met):

```
if (a <= 10)
{
   print ("Incorrect");
}
```

What I need is when the second condition is met then the first message `Correct` doesn't be displayed anymore even if the `a <= 10` again, so I need that `Correct` be permanent "skipped", permanent "disabled" or the correct way it calls, **and now in substitution of** `Correct`, then the new and permanent displayed message be `Incorrect`. So as you can see, in the situation I describe `Incorrect` has more *weight* than `Correct` because once `a <= 10` then the permanent message to be displayed is `Incorrect` ("forever").

For a while I have been using some different combinations of `if` + `else`, and `if` + `else if`, and `if` + and extra separated `if`, but no positive results for now, because yes, I get the `Incorrect` message displayed once the 2nd condition is met but for a strange reason what the code does is once the 2nd condition is met it displays both message on screen `Correct` and `Incorrect`, both at the same time and I don't understand why it could be happening because both conditions are mutually exclusive, so in theory, when once one of them is met what I think is the other is automatically "disabled". I don't know if the fact about both conditions are into a loop makes any special case because this is happening.

```
...
// Here is an example of what I'm using. I tried to put the next in 
// around 10 different ways,either in the same part of the code or in 
// different parts and always the same result, it displays as 
// should `Correct` but when the `a <= 10` is met it displays both messages
// `Correct` and `Incorrect`, 
// and what I need is when this happens, only be displayed `Incorrect` permantly.

if (a <= 10)
{
   print ("Incorrect");
}
else if (a > 10)
{
   print ("Correct");
}
...
```

Note: I think no extra code or context is needed because here we are talking about a very simple logic, for a simple code. By the way I'm using C# but I put the examples with generic code because the main I need is the logic.

Comment: I think what you want is an and clause on your secondary if.

Answer (score 1):

If you want *permanent* (regardless `a`) condition, we have to extract it:

```
  // true : initially, we should check a > 10 condition
  bool isCorrect = true;
```

Please note, that this declaration should not be *local variable*, but a (`static`?) *field* outside the method:

```
  static bool isCorrect = true;
```

then you can use combination of `isCorrect` and `a > 10` condintions

```
  // &&= looks more natural, however only &= operator exists
  if (isCorrect &= a > 10)
      print("Correct");
  else
      print("Incorrect");
```

You can even compress the code in one liner with a help of turnary operator:

```
 print((isCorrect &= a > 10) ? "Correct" : "Incorrect");
```

Note, that whenever `a > 10` doesn't meet, `false` will be assigned to `isCorrect` and from now on `isCorrect` will be `false`.

Comment: I'm in stackoverflow since around 2 weeks and I still can't believethe ultra fast spped the responses arrive. This site is amazing in the best sense of the word. Thank you very much @dmitry-bychenko,  I will try your solution as soon as I be in the PC.

Comment: I just tried, adding the `bool`, the `&=` into the `if` and still the same exact printing result, i.e. the program prints "Correct" when it starts, as should, but once the `else` is met it adds the "Incorrect" also keeping the "Correct". So it is printing "Correct" as should but when it have to replace "Correct" by  "Incorrect" what it does is to print both. I have some hours trying to solve this and I'm unable to get it works, what would be happening in this case? is there any way to "force" to make the printing replacement I need?

Comment: @adiario: where do you put ` bool isCorrect = true;` declaration? this declaration should not be local variable, but some (`static`?) field

Comment: I put the `bool isCorrect = true;` with the rest of variables and constants, right after into `public class Program{}`. And now you mention `static` field, I don't find anything with the word `static` into the code, so I just tried putting the `bool` as `static bool isCorrect = true;` and also treid with `private static bool isCorrect = true;`and still displaying the same results, when it get into the `else` it prints both messages "Correct" & "Incorrect", with the difference that now once reached the `else` when I manually refresh the "script" **then** I see it only shows "Incorrect"